# Excel SUM\SUMIF based on cell number formatting

Tags: excel, format, sum, cell, formula

I have a row containing cells with different formatting

they look the following

- 85
- 32%
- 45
- 23%
- 11
- 5%

the result i need to achieve is to SUM only the number formatted cells (not the percentage ones) without any additional rows. No clue how to do it.

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asuumuing your data is in A1:A6

```
=SUMIF(A1:A6,">"&1)
```

Comment: Glad I was able to help...Would you mind accepting and upvote the answer if this helped....

Comment: Says it requires at least 15 points of reputation, which i am just on my way to earn ... Crap.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this will only work if all numbers in range are positive, I've just tried this with a larger dataset and is excluded negative values - wish I could provide a better solution but I don't know one.